# Mapped LiveData returns null on getValue() call

Tags: android, mapping, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

I was building a viewModel  in my project and and I wrote a LiveData set like this

```
private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
val user= _user 

val id = _user.map {
    if ( something ) {
        value 
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

the problem I faced is that when I observe "id" in a Fragment/Activity , I can recieve the updates from "id" LiveData but if I try to get current value from "id" via "id.value" it returns null even if the "_user" liveData is updated.

Is there any reason for that ? am I missing something ?

Comment: Where are you calling `observe` on your `id` LiveData? You have to observe it for it to ever have a value.

Comment: @ianhanniballake from a fragment in onViewCreated() . Also, yes it returns null otherwise. Moreover , I created a unit test that tests the update of "id"  with using getvalue and observing it (asserting that value is not null). observing passes the test whereas getValue fails as it still returns null

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, and solved it by below code.

```kotlin
val EmptyObservers = mutableMapOf<Class<*>, Observer<*>>()

@MainThread
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T> LiveData<T>.safeGetValue(): T? {
    return if (this is MediatorLiveData && !hasActiveObservers()) {
        val emptyObserver = EmptyObservers.getOrPut(T::class.java) {
            Observer<T> {  }
        } as Observer<T>
        observeForever(emptyObserver)
        value.also { removeObserver(emptyObserver) }
    } else {
        value
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```kotlin
data class User(val name: String, val id: Long)

private val _user: MutableLiveData<User?> = MutableLiveData()
val user: LiveData<User?> = _user

val id: LiveData<Long?> = Transformations.map(_user) {
    it?.id
}

fun getId() { 
    val userId = id.safeGetValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using operator `=` to assign value, this assignment will run on object creation and at this time `_user` has no value, `id` will be null forever whether `_user` is updated or not because it's a one-time assignment

Instead, use `getter` method, so the value is recalculate each time you call `id`:

```
val id
    get() = _user.map {
        if ( something ) {
            value 
        } else {
            null
        }
}
```